# Почему такое распределение бит в памяти?

Tags: python

Почему такое распределение бит в памяти?

```
x = 3
y = 7
print(id(3))
print(id(7))
```

получается

```
1362879447344

1362879447472
```

Почему такое распределение как будто оно сразу для `4 5 6` выделило память?

Comment: Причем здесь память, это просто id объекта. Или я что-nто путаю

Comment: @СергейОстровский, я новичок, но в  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id  сказано что id возвращает "индификатор" объекта, и внизу, как я понял, пояснение, что это адрес объекта в памяти.

Comment: Таки питон действительно выделяет память для чисел от -5 до 256 на старте https://realpython.com/lessons/small-integer-caching/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Распределение такое потому что оно действительно выделило память для 4, 5 и 6 заранее.

Питон кеширует маленькие целые числа чтобы в вычислениях они занимали меньше места. Числа в Питоне - объекты, каждая арифметическая операция порождает новый объект. За одним исключением: если число мало, то это будет проверено и вместо создания нового объекта будет взят объект из кеша. Кеш заполняется на старте интерпретатора.

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong).
[Исходный код](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L284).

Оба выражения равны десять. У них одинаковые `id`, так как десятка в кеше:

```
@>>> id(9 + 1)
140364789449232
@>>> id(11 - 1)
140364789449232
```

Оба выражения равны тысяче. У них разные `id`, так как тысячи в кеше нет. Каждая новая вычисленная тысяча - новый объект:

```
@>>> id(1001 - 1)
140364769497712
@>>> id(999 + 1)
140364769498320
```

Ещё одна демонстрация:

```
ids1 = {i: id(i) for i in range(-1000, 1001)}
ids2 = {i: id(i) for i in range(-1000, 1001)}

for n in (-6, -5, 256, 257):
    print(n, ids1[n] == ids2[n])
```

> ```
> $ python in_cache.py
> -6 False
> -5 True
> 256 True
> 257 False
> ```

Comment: print(id(-101+1))
print(id(-99-1)) я написал вот такой код и у меня вывелось 2 одинаковых значения, потому что у меня после выполнения 1 строчки посчиталось -100 и этот объект из памяти не ушел, когда посчиталась 2 строчка опять -100, но тк этот объект определен заранее, то новый объект не создается, а просто выводится адрес этого объекта. так получается ?

Comment: `-100` не часть кеша. Иногда `id` будут одинаковы даже если значение не в кеше. В вашем случае оба `-100` временные объекты. Можно предположить что они оба выделились и немедленно удалились на одном адресе. Это та причина по которой в последней демке я сохранил значения в словарь. Интерпретатор тогда не может удалить их быстро и вынужден выделять новые значения на новых адресах.

Answer (score 1):

Узнать id объекта в памяти:

```
id('Значение')
```

Узнать сколько занимает памяти:

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof('Значение'))
```

Функция id() возвращает уникальный идентификатор для указанного объекта. Все объекты в Python имеют свой уникальный идентификатор. Идентификатор присваивается объекту при его создании. Идентификатор является адресом памяти объекта и будет отличаться при каждом запуске программы.

Более подробно изложено тут
https://pythobyte.com/id-function-in-python-62441/

Comment: Но если ты сам новичок. Таки зачем вообще нужно это тебе, если не секрет

Comment: значит идентификатор это ссылка на объект ? И также можно сказать что идентификатор это адрес в памяти ? Так получается ?

Comment: ну для полного понимания питона нужно залезть в него.(шутка в том, что питон это змея, и я внутрь залазию))))

Comment: В некотором смысле. Читай про ООП питоновский. Там про ссылки и общение объектов много чего сказано.